# How can I ignore updates when installing SSMS 2012 through CMD?

Tags: sql-server-2012, installation

Current cmd is:

```
setup.exe /ACTION="Install" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /Q /INDICATEPROGRESS /FEATURES="Tools"
```

can't find an update switch to ignore.

Reason for this is that it always hangs when searching for updates. Left it for 45 minutes earlier with no joy.

Thanks,

Comment: Simply [`/UpdateEnabled=FALSE`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2012/12/06/sql-server-2012-setup-just-got-smarter/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex K stated in my comment

`/UpdateEnabled=FALSE`